# Simple math problem in division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I recently did an exam and one of the questions that I got wrong was $\frac {3268} {42}$. My options were:

(a) $77.80$
(b) $78$
(c) $77$
(d) $77.81$

I chose (d); rounding up from $77.80952381$, but they say it should be (a). Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I think this needs context. There are many ways of stopping a decimal sequence. IB (International Baccalaureate), for example, prefers truncation, in which case $77.80$ is correct.

Comment: d) is closer to the $3268/42$, so what was being tested? Were you instructed to round down? Was there any other context to the question, or was it simply a division problem? Have you asked the instructor?

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: It was a simply division problem, with no other criteria. It just said to divide the following. Is there a rule in Truncation, that I'm not aware of? How did you come to the conclusion that 77.80 is correct, Elliot? Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, In reference to the first answer; which now, really has me just as curious for an explanation...Trunaction; as in what a computer does, to limit the amount of digits in a value. Why would the International Baccalaureate truncate only to the hundredth, for an answer like this? Why not just say (c) 77, then? At least a computer will truncate up to 4 decimal places, to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Oh, and thank you for the edit, mrf. It looks much better.